# What is UDDI in the context of webservices?

Tags: web-services, uddi

What is UDDI in the context of Webservice ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UDDI is universal Discription, Discovery and Integration. It is directly that is used to publish and discover public web services. More details are available at site http://www.UDDI.org

Comment: Actually, the real answer is that UDDI is an obsolete failure that is almost never used in practice.

Answer (score 0):

UDDI stands for Universal description, discovery and integration.UDDI is a XML based network directory where web service owners register their web services and client can search, find and invoke web services.

Features of [UDDI](http://www.tutorialscorner.com/webservice/UDDI.html) -

1. UDDI is a XML based registry and platform independent.
2. UDDI works just like a telephone directory where a business can be registered as per its name, geography and the web services it publishes.
3. UDDI Supports SOAP, RMI and CORBA for communication. SOAP is the most popular and common protocol for communication.
4. UDDI registers the WSDL address URL of a web service. A client of the web service searches and finds the WSDL in the UDDI registry. Once received the WSDL can be invoked by using the URL.