# what is difference in UDDI, DISCO and WSDL?

Tags: .net, wcf, web-services

I am reading about web services and read about UDDI, DISCO and WSDL but couldn't understand what is its meaning. I am new to web services. Kindly guide and help me understanding these terms and their mutual relationship.

thanks Thanks THANKS

Comment: [What's the difference between WSDL,DISCO and EVENT?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3656332), [What is UDDI in the context of webservices?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2635823)

Comment: so are you clear now?????.............

Comment: I think [this](http://help.eclipse.org/kepler/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.jst.ws.consumption.ui.doc.user%2Fconcepts%2Fcwsdlud.html) is a very useful resource, in particular: "A service provider hosts a Web service and makes it accessible using protocols such as SOAP/HTTP and SOAP/JMS. The Web service is described by the WSDL documents that are stored on the provider's server or in a special repository. The WSDL documents are referenced by UDDI business services (service documents) and tModels (binding documents). These pointers enable discovery of a Web service by a service requestor."

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can also find details about all this tree on MSDN also...do check it out that also by googling it.

Read more : [Web Services - SOAP, WSDL, Disco and UDDI](http://www.exforsys.com/tutorials/vb.net-2005/web-services-soap-wsdl-disco-and-uddi.html)

**Disco**

The Web Service Discovery Tool (DISCO) is used to discover the URLs of XML Web Services located on a Web server and saves documents related to each XML service on a local disk. The DISCO takes the URL and discovers and produce publishes discovery documents (.wsdl, .xsd, .disco and .dicomap files) as arguments.

**UDDI**

Universal Description, Discovery and Integration (UDDI) is a platform independent framework functioning like a directory that provides a mechanism to locate and register web services on the internet.

**WSDL**

Web Services Description Language (WSDL) is a markup language that describes the web service.